# Android getting the Fixed Tab, PageViewer to load different fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm new to software development and java as a whole, I've been trying for days now to get the default template android gives for fixed tabbed Navigation with pageviewer. Regardless of what I try I can't seem to get it to load anything but the first fragment. all the other onClick tabs events in the Emulator load the very same first fragment defined in the template, sliding the pager has the same effect.

I've tried modifying my code several times till the point where there are little runtime errors, but I still can't get it to load other fragments through the Tabs.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

here's my code.

My projects a Native tablet EHR App

```
    package com.example.medictouch;

    import java.util.Locale;

    import com.example.medictouch.MedicTouchActivity.encountersFragment;
    import com.example.medictouch.MedicTouchActivity.patient_chartFragment;
    import com.example.medictouch.MedicTouchActivity.billingFragment;
    import com.example.medictouch.MedicTouchActivity.medicationsFragment;
    import com.example.medictouch.MedicTouchActivity.treatmentsFragment;
    import com.example.medictouch.MedicTouchActivity.laboratoryFragment;
    import com.example.medictouch.MedicTouchActivity.imagingFragment;
    import com.example.medictouch.MedicTouchActivity.doctors_notesFragment;
    import com.example.medictouch.MedicTouchActivity.departmentsFragment;


    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MedicTouchActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            ActionBar.TabListener {

        /**
         * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
         * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
         * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
         * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
         * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
         * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
         */
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

        /**
         * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
         */
        ViewPager mViewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.medictouch);

            // Set up the action bar.
            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the app.
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

            // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
            // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
            // a reference to the Tab.
            mViewPager
                    .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                        }
                    });

            // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
            for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
                // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
                // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
                // this tab is selected.
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
            // the ViewPager.
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }

        /**
         * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
         * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
         */
        public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
                // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
                // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
                Fragment fragment = new encountersFragment();
                Fragment fragment1 = new patient_chartFragment();
                Fragment fragment2 = new billingFragment();
                Fragment fragment3 = new medicationsFragment();
                Fragment fragment4 = new treatmentsFragment();
                Fragment fragment5 = new laboratoryFragment();
                Fragment fragment6 = new imagingFragment();
                Fragment fragment7 = new doctors_notesFragment();
                Fragment fragment8 = new departmentsFragment();

                return fragment;
            }





            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // Show 6 total pages.
                return 10;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toLowerCase();
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toLowerCase();
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toLowerCase();
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section4).toLowerCase();
                case 4:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section5).toLowerCase();
                case 5:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section6).toLowerCase();
                case 6:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section7).toLowerCase();
                case 7:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section8).toLowerCase();
                case 8:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section9).toLowerCase();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
         * displays dummy text.
         */
        public class encountersFragment extends Fragment {

            private final int title_section1 = 0;
            public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = title_section1;


            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.encounters,
                        container, false);

                return rootView;
            }
        }


    public class patient_chartFragment extends Fragment {

        private final int title_section2 = 1;
        public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = title_section2;

        public patient_chartFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_chart,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public class billingFragment extends Fragment {

        private final int title_section3 = 2;
        public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = title_section3;

        public billingFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.billing,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public class medicationsFragment extends Fragment {

        public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 3;

        public medicationsFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.medications,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public class treatmentsFragment extends Fragment {

        public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 4;

        public treatmentsFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.treatments,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public class laboratoryFragment extends Fragment {

        public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 5;

        public laboratoryFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.labs,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public class imagingFragment extends Fragment {

        public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 6;

        public imagingFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imaging,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public class doctors_notesFragment extends Fragment {

        public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 7;

        public doctors_notesFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctors_notes,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public class departmentsFragment extends Fragment {

        public final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 8;

        public departmentsFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.departments,
                    container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use switch..case.. block in `getItem(int position)` method. Use below code.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
    // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
    Fragment fragment;
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        fragment = new encountersFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new patient_chartFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new billingFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new medicationsFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new treatmentsFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new laboratoryFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new imagingFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new doctors_notesFragment();
        break;
    case 8:
        fragment = new departmentsFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

**Edit:**

I found this error in your code(may have more errors). You are using AutoCompletTextView in xml change it to **AutoCompleteTextView**

```
08-16 21:53:46.247: E/AndroidRuntime(4768): Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.AutoCompletTextView" on 
path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.medictouch-
2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.medictouch-2, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: Thanks Ketan, you're the man. its working for the very first time eve, but there's a slight problem after that. all the Tabs are shrunk into the view and non of the text is displaying. and the app force exits after a few min of tab switching. I'm wondering if I should use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead. and also if split actionbar would solve the Tab title displaying issue. Thanks once again

Comment: Glad it worked for you...can you post logcat error ? Are you using PagerTitleStrip or PagerTabStrip ?

Comment: I'm having difficulty posting the logcat in the comment box, or in the main question. I'm trying to put that in an online text editor and link it here rather. however in trying the FragmentStatePage Adaptor all the get int lines of code are flagged. Non yet with respect to PageTitleStrip or PagerTabStrip??

Comment: Sorry to bother with my code but here my new code implementing FragmentSatePageAdaptor which has some erors with all the lines concerning Get (int) etc. Ultimately my App works with persistent data with each viewpager fragment. and I was wondering if there a way for me to define a different class to work on each fragment and how to go about setting up the link from here or link each of them together of just creating them and refrencing them from here.        Thanks for your help and time already given. http://pastebin.com/embed.php?i=ketYh7Ch